# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\posts()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two classes in Models (Post and User)

The method **posts()** in Models/User.php

Models:

```
 public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    
    $this->validate($request, [
        'body' => 'required'
    ]);
    
    $request->user()>posts()->create([
        'body' => $request->body
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Take a close look at `$request->user()>posts()->create([`. You're missing a `-`, and are thus doing `$request->user()   >   posts()...`.

Answer (score 1):

I just missed the symbol - before "posts()" as @ceejayoz mentioned in the comment

**what makes me confused** is that i use posts() method in another controller and show the same error even if it's well written

[Screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJEXu.png)

Comment: That screenshot looks like your IDE getting confused; I'll bet it works fine when actually run. We run https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper to address this sort of problem.

Comment: I will install it right now thanks.